# Prestashop 1.7.7 create a ToggleColumn on a custom field

Tags: php, prestashop

In my database I have a field `isVerified` which is a `bool : 0 / 1`.

I want to create a `ToggleColumn` so whenever I click on the admin panel it switches to `true / 1` and I perform an action like sending a mail.

Here is what I made so far :

- Create a `isVerified` column in the database set it to a `bool default 0`
- Create :

  ```
            ->add((new ToggleColumn('isVerified'))
            ->setName('Verify')
            ->setOptions([
                'field' => 'isVerified',
                'primary_field' => 'id_customer',
                'route' => 'admin_customers_toggle_verify',
                'route_param_name' => 'customerId'
            ])
        )
  ```
- Parameter a route in `customers.yml` :

`

```
admin_customers_toggle_verify:
          path: /{customerId}/toggle-verify
          methods: [POST]
          defaults:
            _controller: PrestaShopBundle:Admin/Sell/Customer/Customer:toggleVerify
            _legacy_controller: AdminCustomers
            _legacy_link: AdminCustomers:verifycustomer
            _legacy_parameters:
              id_customer: customerId
          requirements:
            customerId: \d+
```

- Created a `toggleVeryfyAction` method in the `CustomerController` :
  `$editableCustomer = $this->getQueryBus()->handle(new GetCustomerForEditing((int) $customerId)); $editCustomerCommand = new EditCustomerCommand((int) $customerId); $editCustomerCommand->setIsVerified(!$editableCustomer->isVerified()); $this->getCommandBus()->handle($editCustomerCommand);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is adding fields into theses files :

```
- CustomerFormDataProvider
- CustomerFormDataHandler
- AddCustomerCommand
- EditCustomerCommand
- GetCustomerForEditingHandler
- EditableCustomer
- CustomerType
```